# Remove rowid (not rowname) from tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rowid, tibble

How can I remove the `rowid` from a tibble?

Example:

```
require(tibble)

tibble(x = letters[1:3],
       y = letters[4:6])

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <chr> <chr>
1     a     d
2     b     e
3     c     f
```

I want to remove 1,2,3.

**Note I:** the rowid is not the rowname! I know how to remove rownames.

**Note II:** I want to remove the id since i want to convert the table to latex via `xtable::xtable()`. Here the rowid is put in its own column (which i dont need)

Comment: Just convert it to `vector` i.e. `tbl[[1]]`  Isn't this rownames?

Comment: I actually have a larger data frame whose structure i need to preserve. Changed to example to make that more clear

Comment: That is just how it's printed

Comment: so there is no way to change it?

Comment: You may need to change the print method

Comment: There should be no need to change it in the first place since it's not part of the structure you want to preserve. It's just printed

Comment: @docendodiscimus unfortunately not for xtable. see my edit

Comment: I get that only as row names in the xtable

Comment: From linked post: `print(xtable(x), include.rownames = FALSE)`

Comment: @zx8754 thanks for pointing to the already answerd question

Comment: No problem, no offence intended when closing as duplicate. Better for the site all good answers in one place, and all related questions pointing to the same resource. It is good to have duplicated questions, only when they are closed as duplicates.